# Displaying a returned string from a function with React & TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase

I have a Firebase database of "Tasks" that contains a userID property. I'm trying to run a function to get the username from the userID property and display it.

Because I'm displaying the Task data and the username inside of a map function I can't set the username with a useState.

Here's how the component return function looks right now:

```
return (
        <>
            <Container style={{ width: 'auto', border: 'solid 0.2rem', borderRadius: '2rem', marginTop: '2rem', padding: '3rem' }}>
                <h1>Tasks</h1>
                {taskList?.map((task: Task) => (
                    <Card key={task.id} style={{ width: '30rem', padding: '2rem' }}>
                        <h3>{task.title}</h3>
                        <p>{task.description}</p>
                        <p>{task.timeCreated.toDate().toDateString()}</p>
                        <p>Created By: {getUserName(task.userID)}</p>
                        <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => deleteTask(task, task.id)}>Delete Task</Button>
                    </Card>
                ))}
            </Container>
        </>
    )
```

As you can see for each Task in `taskList` I'm displaying a card with the `task.title`, `task.description`, time created and the username by trying to use `getUserName(task.userID)`

The `getUserName()` function is as follows:

```
const getUserName = async(taskID: string) : Promise<string> => {
        const docRef = doc(db, "tasks/" + taskID);
        const taskDocument = await getDoc(docRef);
        const userData = taskDocument.data() as UserData;
        return userData.name;
    }
```

The error I'm getting is in the Component return statement.
`Type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)`

No idea where to go from here. I'm just trying to output the users name within the return function of the component.

Comment: `async - await` function returns promise object. I think you have to pre-fetch  taskDocument before rendering.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: extract taskID from taskList and Promise.all([...fetchData]).then((res) => { ...combine taskList & res });

Comment: I mean, After requesting taskList, using taskIDs to request getDoc and combine taskList & response of getDoc

Comment: OR I recommand to use 3rd party library like react-promise?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `<Username userId={userId} />` component like this (pseudo code):

```js
const Username = ({userId}) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsername = async () => {
      setUsername(await getUserName(userId));
    }

    fetchUsername()
  }, []);

  return <div>{username}</div>
}
```

And use this component in the map.